# Java socket server, C# socket client, communication problems?

Tags: c#, java, sockets, client

Erm, I'm new to sockets and even newer to Java, so the Java side is basically copied and pasted. The C# side is a little more self-made.

I've come to think that it may be some difference in the way Java and C# interpret strings; I've gotten it to partially work using the now deprecated "readLine" method in Java.

On the C# side:

```
    private void pollChat()
    {
        while (clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream);
                msg(returndata);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                clientSocket.Close();
                msg("Socket Exception");
            }
        }
    }
```

... for receiving things, (I changed System.Text.Encoding.ASCII to UTF8, but it didn't help) ... and

```
                NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nickname + ": " + textBoxToSubmit.Text + "$");
                serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
                serverStream.Flush();
```

... for sending things.

On the Java server side...

```
void sendToAll( String message ) {

    synchronized( outputStreams ) {

        for (Enumeration e = getOutputStreams(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {

            DataOutputStream dout = (DataOutputStream)e.nextElement();

            try {
                dout.writeBytes( message );
            } catch( IOException ie ) { System.out.println( ie ); }

        }
    }
}
```

... for sending things, and

```
        while (true) {

            // ... read the next message ...
            String message = din.readUTF();

            // ... tell the world ...
            System.out.println( "Sending "+message );

            // ... and have the server send it to all clients
            server.sendToAll( message );

        }
```

... for receiving things.

I apologize for the giant amount of pasted code, but please bear with me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't said what the actual problem is.  "Communication problems" is very vague.

Comment: Can you post what behavior you are getting that you're not expecting... using both UTF8 and ASCII? If you're fine with just English letters I'd recommend going back to ASCII so you can concentrate on one issue at a time.

Comment: Well, I've managed to make the C# side transmit to the Java server, but now I'm confused as to how to let Java transmit back to the C# side.
Please see the "answer" below, that I posted.

Comment: So your actual question is _"How do I transmit data back to a Java Socket from a C# socket?"_ Perhaps it's worthwhile thinking about your question a bit first and updating it instead of referring to "communication problems", ... it might lead to less communication problems. ;p

Comment: @StevenJeuris you realize this thread is almost three years old? Even if that were my question (I don't have the time to check right now), I don't think hostility would help "communication."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that you're trying to read a Unicode string directly from a stream. This is problematic for two reasons.

1. UTF characters are two bytes so
   calling a read when you have an odd
   number of bytes in your buffer is
   either going to block or just cause
   garbage to come out. Neither one is preferable.
2. When you convert your string to
   bytes in C# and send them off there's no header specifying the
   length of the data nor is there a
   terminator character specified so there's no
   way to tell at the receiving end (Java in this case) if the string is
   complete.

I wouldn't recommend using readUTF or any function besides the one that pulls out raw bytes. Once you've handled the two issues I've noted above you'll have a byte array with a complete message. Only then should you try to convert the bytes into their proper encoding scheme.

Comment: Please see the "answer" that I posted.
Thanks!

Comment: Selecting as answer because @StevenJeuris seems to be on some sort of crusade about resolving three year old questions. From what I can tell, this answer helped me find a solution.